# Using Ajax lazy load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, lazy-loading

I created a database where I store all the images' names so that I can retrieve it later on. To retrieve the images' names, I use ajax and bind it with `<img>` tag:

```
$.post('image_name.php',{id:id}, function(data){
   $('#container').html('<img src="img/'+data+'">');
});
```

Everything works great. But what I noticed was, all the images shows up at the same time which slows the process a little bit. Therefore, I am thinking that the best way to handle this issue is to use lazy load. I want any data that is ready to be displayed.... but I do not know how to.

Additonal Info: I am trying to create a list of thumbnails. Just like the Imgur sidebar (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbtPn.jpg)

Comment: how about using a jQuery plugin? http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: I am not trying to lazy load the image, I am trying to lazy load the data I am retrieve from my database

Comment: ok...and to clarify, you want to lazy load image src's which are not visible on screen?

Comment: i am trying to lazy load this data "function(data)".  lazy load image is a different topic.

Comment: apply your code when your images are supposed to be loaded, or if you only want to lazy load src data, only set that data like $("img").attr("src",data)

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to create a list with left / right button:

1. With ajax fetch array of next 6 images. Only names or ids.
2. On ajax success:

   - create a loop for array of images $(array).each in jquery is nice!
   - in loop cycle set one time timer (http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/timers is great) for each image. Use index of array * Interval * 1000 (1000ms for 1 sec)

Whole idea is:

```
onsuccess:
    $(whatyougotfromajax).each(function(index, value)
    {
        $.oneTime(index * Interval * 1000, function()
        {
            $('#block').append('<img src="sth.php?Id=' + value + '">');
        });
    });
```

I im not sure... Not, I'm sure it is not work in this way, but you've got the idea